# What is the proper way to debug a slow internet connection?

Tags: networking, performance, internet, lag

I turn to super users for their best tips. Consider the following scenarios:

- A large house with many roommates with many devices and no way to tell which one is the issue
- Skype choppy, youtube choppy, or games lagging
- Background processes doing downloads unbeknownst the user on many devices
- Both Wifi that is poor, or LAN that is solid

Comment: Why not just disconnect everything, and connect one by one until the problem arises?

Answer (score -1):

**Install vnstat** and it gives logs the usage on a network interface and you can display the usage over different time periods.

(Or)

**Use NTM for monitoring**.

NTM is a network traffic monitor for Linux where you can easily monitor your network usage. In case if you are using wifi then was easily resolved in the preferences window by changing the interface to “**wlan0**"

For further details on NTM please check the same and update us.

http://ubuntunigeria.wordpress.com/2010/08/18/monitor-your-data-usage-on-ubuntu-easily-using-ntm/

Comment: This is not really answering the question. **many devices and no way to tell which one is the issue** what about all the not Ubuntu devices?